# Grouping the Map Keys based on the part of the key in Java 8

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, java-8, hashmap

I have a ***map*** which contains information as below:

```
"source.temp.temp1.issuer.value": "Hend",
"source.temp.temp2.issuer.value": "Ledge",
"source.temp.temp1.issuer.audence": "Legos1",
"source.temp.temp2.issuer.audence": "Legos2",
"source.temp.temp1.issuer.algp": "esc",
"source.temp.temp2.issuer.algp": "esc"
```

I need to do grouping based on the part of the key, i.e `temp1`, `temp2`, etc. Save them and make a ***list*** out of it. So the final result should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "source.temp.temp1.issuer.value": "Hend",
        "source.temp.temp1.issuer.audence": "Legos1",
        "source.temp.temp1.issuer.algp": "esc"
    },
    {
        "source.temp.temp2.issuer.value": "Ledge",
        "source.temp.temp2.issuer.audence": "Legos2",
        "source.temp.temp2.issuer.algp": "esc"
    },
    ...
]
```

The keys are of `Object` type.

Comment: Could you please give feedback on whether [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71725106/17949945) worked for you, or you have encountered some issues and this problem remains unresolved?

Answer (score 2):

With Stream API, you can do it by utilizing the collector [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)).

The `classifier` function that needs to be passed as an argument will replace everything after `"issue"` with an empty string. By default, `groupingBy()` collects all elements mapped to the same key into a list.

```
Map<String, String> source =
         Map.of("source.temp.temp1.issuer.value", "Hend",
                "source.temp.temp2.issuer.value", "Ledge",
                "source.temp.temp1.issuer.audence", "Legos1",
                "source.temp.temp2.issuer.audence", "Legos2",
                "source.temp.temp1.issuer.algp", "esc",
                "source.temp.temp2.issuer.algp", "esc");

Map<Object, List<String>> result =
        source.keySet().stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> str.replaceAll("\\.issuer(.)*", "")));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

```
source.temp.temp2=[source.temp.temp2.issuer.value, source.temp.temp2.issuer.algp, source.temp.temp2.issuer.audence]
source.temp.temp1=[source.temp.temp1.issuer.algp, source.temp.temp1.issuer.audence, source.temp.temp1.issuer.value]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this, added comments in every steps.

```
        List<Map<String, String>> groups = source.entrySet().stream() //take maps entryset stream
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e->e.getKey().contains("temp1")?"tempKey1":"tempKey2")) //group based on your term/logic Result will be <newKey, List<Entry>>
            .values().stream() //Ignore newly created key take values alone into stream again => result stream of Entry
            .map(entryList-> {
                return entryList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey(), e->e.getValue()));
            }) //Convert entry into Map
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); //collect stream of map into List of map
    System.out.println(groups);
```

In ***groupingBy*** you can change the login whatever you want. Currently I hardcoded with ***temp1*** & ***temp2*** alone.